# Error is occuring at mMap.setMapStyle(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL); , Why?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapStyle(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL); // I am geting error at this line

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng Sydney = new LatLng(21.4733161,-78.2499502);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Sydney).title("Sydney").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Sydney, 10));
    }
```

While trying to get Map in different style, I am getting error in doing so.

Error is
error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to MapStyleOptions
        mMap.setMapStyle(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

I am using AndroidStudio 3.6.2. I have GooglePlayServices installed. What else I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#change_the_map_type), if you're using `GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL`, you should be using the `setMapType()` method, not `setMapStyle()`:

```
mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Great! Make sure to accept the answer to hitting the check box next to this answer to remove the question from the list of unanswered questions. Best of luck!

Comment: Ya Of course! New to the community that's why unaware.